# How did I get a bonus on my answer directly?

Tags: support, bounties

I got a +50 on my answer to one of the questions on SE, and found that the answer was awarded bounty by somebody. I didn't find any explanation of this on the help topic for 'bounties'. All that's given is that a question is eligible for bounty, someone can award a bounty from their own reputation and some time is allowed to pass before it can be awarded. But nothing of this sort.

Can someone explain to me what's going on?

Link to the said answer:
[What is the opposite of higher in "Bounce me higher"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75215/what-is-the-opposite-of-higher-in-bounce-me-higher/76521#76521)

Comment: Link to the answer?

Comment: @Oded Added link.

Comment: Someone awarded you a bounty most likely

Comment: @Robotnik or it was awarded automatically. It says on the tooltip who awarded the bounty.

Comment: @ChrisF - true, but in this case it was awarded manually :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is more detailed that the page I referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone started a bounty a few days before you answered.

This same person awarded the bounty a few days afterwards to your answer.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but at the time it seemed like it was awarded directly. It may happen that a bounty was started and awarded after I answered, I don't remember. Anyways, I am active on multiple SE sites, I usually don't look at a question again unless notified. :)

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, you were awarded a **[Bounty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)** for your answer!

> ### What is a bounty? How can I start one?
>
> If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.
>   - <sub>[Help Center > Reputation & Moderation > What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)</sub>

Anyone can place a bounty on any question, including their own. In doing so, they offer up some of their own rep as a reward (or 'bounty') to gather answers.

If you look at the [revision history](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/75215/revisions) of the question itself, it says that

- A Bounty was started (worth 50 reputation) by user *TheIndependentAquarius*
- The reason for the bounty was to *Draw Attention* to the question
- 5 days later, *TheIndependentAquarius* chose **your** answer to be rewarded the bounty.

> ### How is a bounty awarded?
>
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)
>   - <sub>[Help Center > Reputation & Moderation > What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)</sub>